# Accessing added jquery elements added with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that uses a multidimensional array to give me convertions by reference :

```
var sizechanges = Array(
    Array (6,8,10,12), //type A
    Array(4,6,8,10)); //typeb
```

When a dropdown is changed in the html the value is obtained and a second dropdown is populated- code below (this works) and the log is as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#size0").on('change',function(){
        var b0 = $('#size0').val();
        var i = sizechanges[b0].length;
        var blohtmml = ("<option>PLEASE SELECT</option>");
        x = 0;
        while ( x < i ) { 
            blohtmml += ("<option value='" + x + "'>" + sizechanges[b0][x] + "</option>") ;
            console.log(sizechanges[b0][x]); works
            x++;
        }
        $('#size1').html(blohtmml); //works
    });
});
```

So the above works. Where I am having trouble is accessing the content added by html() method. My code is below:

```
$("#butt").on('click',function(){ //button id is #butt
    var b1 = $('#size1').val();//size dropdown
    var b2 = $('#size2').val();// country to dropdown
    console.log(b1,b2); //nothing in log
    var result = sizechanges[b2][b1];
    console.log(result); //nothing in log
});
```

I can see that the source is not updated and was wondering how I can access the added content. I read many questions on append but can not find anything on html(). I guessing the solutions are similar but do not understand why the .on method is not finding the new HTML.

Lastly I am not getting any result for b2 which is a dropdown unaffected by the html insertion.

My HTML is added below for completeness.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color: lightblue;">                        
            <form><label>I AM IN</LABEL><select id="size0" class="size0">
                            <option>PLEASE SELECT
                            </option>
                            <option value="1">
                                UK
                            </option>
                            <option value="0">
                                US
                            </option>


                </select><br>

                <label>size to convert </label>
                <select id="size1" class="size1">
                            <option>PLEASE SELECT
                            </option>


                </select><br>
                <label>IS IN </label>
                <select class="size2" id="size23">
                  <option>PLEASE SELECT</option>
                            <option value="1"> UK</option>
  <option value="0"> US</option>
</select><br>


         <button id="butt" type="button" >GET SIZE</button>

            </form>
            <div id="blobla"></div>
            <div id="blobla2"></div> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Any help solving my problem will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Make sure you don't mix up *class* with *id* (`#` vs `.`)

Comment: I was just experimenting with class/id and found the js code easier to change having things named the same. I believe (hope) that this is not my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<select class="size2" id="size23">`
```

to:

```
<select class="size2" id="size2">
```

And you might have better luck.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sizechanges = Array(
        Array (6,8,10,12), //type A
        Array(4,6,8,10)); //typeb
  
    $("#size0").on('change',function(){
        var b0 = $('#size0').val();
        var i = sizechanges[b0].length;
        var blohtmml = ("<option>PLEASE SELECT</option>");
        x = 0;
        while ( x < i ) { 
            blohtmml += ("<option value='" + x + "'>" + sizechanges[b0][x] + "</option>") ;
            console.log(sizechanges[b0][x]); //works
            x++;
        }
        $('#size1').html(blohtmml); //works
    });
    $("#butt").on('click',function(){ //button id is #butt
        var b1 = $('#size1').val();//size dropdown
        var b2 = $('#size2').val();// country to dropdown
        console.log(b1,b2); //nothing in log
        var result = sizechanges[b2][b1];
        console.log(result); //nothing in log
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form><label>I AM IN</LABEL><select id="size0" class="size0">
                            <option>PLEASE SELECT
                            </option>
                            <option value="1">
                                UK
                            </option>
                            <option value="0">
                                US
                            </option>


                </select><br>

                <label>size to convert </label>
                <select id="size1" class="size1">
                            <option>PLEASE SELECT
                            </option>


                </select><br>
                <label>IS IN </label>
                <select class="size2" id="size2">
                  <option>PLEASE SELECT</option>
                            <option value="1"> UK</option>
  <option value="0"> US</option>
</select><br>


         <button id="butt" type="button" >GET SIZE</button>

            </form>
            <div id="blobla"></div>
            <div id="blobla2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this spot. It works. However my code with the change did not work. There are some minor differences in your code that have done the trick. i.e doc.ready at top of js file. Many thanks for your help and the code snippet (as I would not have picked up minor differences).